# VlookUp giving last value of each month

Tags: excel

Hi i have this Excel file:

```
    Date    GBP_S(t)  A
27/12/88    1,80400
28/12/88    1,78900
29/12/88    1,78950
30/12/88    1,80850
 2/01/89    0,00000
 3/01/89    1,82250
 4/01/89    1,80700
 5/01/89    1,79700
 6/01/89    1,78000
 9/01/89    1,76360
10/01/89    1,76370
11/01/89    1,78100
12/01/89    1,78400
13/01/89    1,77870
16/01/89    0,00000
17/01/89    1,76800
18/01/89    1,75450
19/01/89    1,75000
20/01/89    1,76850
23/01/89    1,77400
24/01/89    1,76770
25/01/89    1,77100
26/01/89    1,77350
27/01/89    1,75800
30/01/89    1,76180
31/01/89    1,75000
 1/02/89    1,75350
 2/02/89    1,75080
 3/02/89    1,74150
 6/02/89    1,73270
 7/02/89    1,74250
 8/02/89    1,74330
 9/02/89    1,75480
10/02/89    1,75430
13/02/89    1,74950
14/02/89    1,76850
15/02/89    1,77330
16/02/89    1,77080
17/02/89    1,77600
20/02/89    0,00000
21/02/89    1,75020
22/02/89    1,75050
23/02/89    1,76000
24/02/89    1,75300
27/02/89    1,74480
28/02/89    1,74400
 1/03/89    1,72400
 2/03/89    1,72380
 3/03/89    1,72300
 6/03/89    1,72200
 7/03/89    1,72170
 8/03/89    1,71970
 9/03/89    1,71750
10/03/89    1,71550
13/03/89    1,71150
14/03/89    1,72720
15/03/89    1,71900
16/03/89    1,71790
17/03/89    1,71300
20/03/89    1,71030
21/03/89    1,72000
22/03/89    1,72280
23/03/89    1,72180
24/03/89    1,71900
27/03/89    1,71000
28/03/89    1,68800
29/03/89    1,68860
30/03/89    1,68750
31/03/89    1,68520
 3/Apr/89   1,68600
 ...
```

I am trying to build a simple VlookUp function but its not working. 
I want a procv function that gives me on the third column(A) the last value of each month o Date column.

So: A1= 1,80850;A2=1,75000; and so on...

Any help?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: (FYI "Procv" is Portuguese for "VlookUp")

Comment: Thanks, Bruce. Edited.

Comment: lol at this question just after brexit XD

Answer (score 3):

I personally would use a helper column in this instance:

In C2 put the following:

```
=IF(MONTH($A2)<>MONTH($A3),MAX($C$1:$C1)+1,"")
```

And copy down the length of the data

This will increment a number on the same row as the last recorded day of each month.

Then you can use that column in an INDEX/MATCH to return the values at the end of each month:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(ROW(1:1),C:C,0)),"")
```

And copy down till you get empty cells.

[image]

---

If you want it all in one formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$194,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$193)-1)/(MONTH($A$2:$A$193)<>MONTH($A$3:$A$194)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

It uses the data from the sheet above.  It is a little harder to understand.

Comment: @Laorie - I agree with Scott.  There's no way to express what you want with stock formulas (without using a helper column) that I know of.  Also, from my experience any kind of custom VBA function for lookup will have pretty terrible performance.

Comment: @JamesFaix see edit.  One formula.  If it was me I would use the one formula method but found that it opens more question than help on sites like this.